# Using Maven to build an Java SDK Mulesoft plugin snapshot

Tags: java, maven, mulesoft, mule4, mule-sdk

We have a Maven build/deploy configuration which we use to build/deploy Mulesoft API's. So the build configuration POM file and settings.xml file seems ok. We can create snapshots and releases without a problem and we can push the builds to the  Azure devops artifact repository.

Now I have also created a Mulesoft Java SDK plugin conform this [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/latest/getting-started). The builded jar  can be loaded as a dependency in other Mulesoft API's.

The problem is that I can only create releases so with Maven version tags like this:

```
<version>0.0.11</version>
```

When I create a snapshot so with the -SNAPSHOT tag  which in maven POM file look like this:

```
<version>0.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Then I get an error when running this commandline:

```
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests --settings C:\tools\mavenmule\conf\settingsSecretsRemoved2.xml
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
 (default-deploy) on project mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact nl.mycompany.mule.modules:mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module:pom:0.0.11-20240318.202914-1 from/to mule-snapshots (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): authentication failed for https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/nl/mycompany/mule/modules/mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module/0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module-0.0.11-20240318.202914-1.pom, status: 401 Unauthorized
```

the maven POM file of that API file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.mycompany.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-extension</packaging>
    <name>Mule-excel-hyperlink-planning-module Extension</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-modules-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.8.2</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    
    
      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <!-- Azure Devops repository to -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Integraties</id>
            <url>https://<Azuredevopslink>/_packaging/Integraties/maven/v1</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- Azure Devops repository to deploy artifacts to -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Integraties</id>
            <url>https://<Azuredevopslink>/_packaging/Integraties/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And my settingsSecretsRemoved2.xml file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>C:/work/mavenrepositories/***company***</localRepository>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <proxies/>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>exchange-test</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>MuleRepository</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>Mule-EE</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>releases-ee</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>mulesoft-releases-ee</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>Integraties</id>
            <username>***account***</username>
            <password>***secret***</password>
        </server>
        -->
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Mule-EE</id>
            <properties>
                <cloudhub-username>exchange-asset-company</cloudhub-username>
                <cloudhub-password>***secret***</cloudhub-password>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>MuleRepository</id>
                    <name>MuleRepository</name>
                    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>archetype-repository</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>archetype</id>
                    <name>Mule Repository</name>
                    <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Integraties</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>Integraties</id>
                    <url>https://</azuredevopslink>/_packaging/Integraties/maven/v1</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

So the strange thing is that the error is pointed to this repo:

https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public

But I don't use that in my configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repository is coming from the parent pom `<distributionManagement>` section of the parent pom. Child poms inherit that configuration from the parent pom. In your pom you overwrote the parent `<repository>` but not the `<snapshotRepository>` element. You need to add that sub element to the `<distributionManagement>` of your pom.

Example:

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Integraties</id>
            <url>https://<Azuredevopslink>/_packaging/Integraties/maven/v1</url>
        ...
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>Integraties-snapshots</id>
            <name>Integraties Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://...</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: THANKS, Really great, it works like a charm I worked a couple of days on this problem also with the help of Mulesoft support with no success.  I will tip this solution also to Mulesoft support.